# Python weave is abnormally slow when using calloc

Tags: c++, python, c, numpy, scipy

I use the following code to make an in-place forward-backward FIR filtering :

```
lena = len(a)
lenb = len(b)
convol = zeros(a.shape)

code = """
            // Forward convolution
            int pad = (lenb-1)/2;
            int i, j;

            for (i=pad; i<pad+lena; i++)
            {
                int kmin, kmax, k;
                // Reverse indexing for the next pass
                j = lena-1-i+pad;

                convol(j)  = 0;

                kmin = (i >= lenb - 1) ? i - (lenb - 1) : 0;
                kmax = (i <  lena - 1) ? i : lena - 1;

                for (k = kmin; k <= kmax; k++)
                {
                  convol(j)  += a(k)*b(i - k);
                }                       
            }


            // Backward convolution (the signal in convol has been
            // reversed using reversed indexes)            
            for (i=pad; i<pad+lena; i++)
            {
                int kmin, kmax, k;
                // Reverse indexing for reordering the output vector
                j = lena-1-i+pad;

                a(j)  = 0;

                kmin = (i >= lenb - 1) ? i - (lenb - 1) : 0;
                kmax = (i <  lena - 1) ? i : lena - 1;

                for (k = kmin; k <= kmax; k++)
                {
                  a(j)  += convol(k)*b(i - k);
                }                       
            }                
            return_val = 1;
       """

weave.inline(code, [ 'a', 'b', 'lena', 'lenb', 'convol'],
type_converters=converters.blitz, compiler = 'g++')
```

Of course the “convol” variable does not need to be seen outside of the C/C++ scope and I need both space and processing optimality. So, it makes sense (at least to me) to replace this code by the following:

```
lena = len(a)
lenb = len(b)

code = """
            // Forward convolution
            int pad = (lenb-1)/2;
            int i, j;

            float* convol = (float*) calloc(lena, sizeof(float));             

            for (i=pad; i<pad+lena; i++)
            {
                int kmin, kmax, k;
                // Reverse indexing for the next pass
                j = lena-1-i+pad;

                convol[j]  = 0;

                kmin = (i >= lenb - 1) ? i - (lenb - 1) : 0;
                kmax = (i <  lena - 1) ? i : lena - 1;

                for (k = kmin; k <= kmax; k++)
                {
                  convol[j]  += a(k)*b(i - k);
                }                       
            }


            // Backward convolution (the signal in convol has been
            // reversed using reversed indexes)            
            for (i=pad; i<pad+lena; i++)
            {
                int kmin, kmax, k;
                // Reverse indexing for reordering the output vector
                j = lena-1-i+pad;

                a(j)  = 0;

                kmin = (i >= lenb - 1) ? i - (lenb - 1) : 0;
                kmax = (i <  lena - 1) ? i : lena - 1;

                for (k = kmin; k <= kmax; k++)
                {
                  a(j)  += convol[k]*b(i - k);
                }                       
            }                

            free(convol);

            return_val = 1;
       """

weave.inline(code, [ 'a', 'b', 'lena', 'lenb'],
type_converters=converters.blitz, compiler = 'g++')
```

Where the only difference is instead of using a numpy array I used directly a C float array. The problem is that the second code takes about 2 times longer to process than the first one… why is that? Is there something wrong in the second version? It should be faster…!

Comment: did you get your versions switched?

Comment: @mgilson Yeah. Sorry about that. It has been corrected.

Comment: @jsn I use it for filtering 8 hours recording of EEG at 256Hz, so about 7,000,000...

Comment: You are `calloc`ing a 25MB block. I wouldn't think it would even return. Any memory allocation beyond a certain amount (I think in this case - M_MMAP_THRESHOLD), would in some instances not return or be considerably slower.

Comment: I shouldn't say "not return", but rather return a `NULL`. You also note that the 25MB block needs to be contiguous and might be hard to find.

Comment: @jsn I did not ran into cases where the allocation failed so far (although I have not reached the point to test this code very much since it is too slow anyway). I also tried the new operator, which produced similar results than calloc. To try getting around the problem you discussed, I tried using std::vector. It resulted in an execution 4.5x slower than the first version... I do not know what is under the hood of the weave.blitz converters but it looks very efficient.

Comment: I mean, if malloc/calloc can't find 25MB in memory, it could go directly to disk, explaining some of the degraded performance.

Comment: Why are you forward-backward filtering with an FIR filter?  Is your filter asymmetric such that it does not have linear phase?

Comment: @Warren Weckesser Because I don't want a linear phase relationship, I want no phase shift at all.

Comment: What type of FIR filter are you using?

Comment: @Warren Weckesser I convolve a windows obtained with scipy firwin to the signal as proposed in [this](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/ApplyFIRFilter). I've took the code of the scipy filtfilt function and modified it until I realised that the best way to obtain better memory management was to use weave as proposed in [this](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/87699)

Comment: OK, in that case, there is no need to use the forward-backward technique--it doesn't do anything useful.  The FIR filter is symmetric, so reversing the order has no effect.  All you are doing is applying the FIR filter twice.  You can check this by comparing `convolve(b, convolve(b, x)[::-1])[::-1]` with `convolve(bb, x)`, where `bb = convolve(b, b)`.  They will be the same, up to normal numerical floating point errors.  (The forward-backward technique is useful for IIR filters.)